# Android use Google Maps API without Google Account in the mobile device

Tags: android, google-maps, user-accounts

Is it possible to use the Google Maps API (show maps, get coordinates, etc...) without having a Google Account configured in the device?

If it is possible, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

No, You need Google account to get API key, which it will be used for accessing the Google Maps API

You can refer to this [page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#get_an_api_key_from_the_console_name) on how to create and use the API key for your project

Comment: Yeah, I already have an app working with maps but the problem is that this app that I developed is for a company and they provided to their workers a company phone for each of them and these phones are not configured with a google account because these are new phones and the app forces the users to set a Google account and the company doesn't like this because the users are not allowed to download other apps in these phones, this is the reason of my question

Comment: So the company is not Google Apps Customer? then I think you need to use Google for Work. you’ll need to verify a domain during the setup process to prove domain ownership and get access to the Google Admin console to [set up Android for Work](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/6174046?hl=en)

Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/support) for more information


I hope this will help you